# sass vars in extjs custom theme

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In an Extjs custom theme, sass/etc/all.scss gets compiled before the sass variables are defined. Is there a better file for creating custom css that can share sass vars we've set for the rest of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Viewport is used for that purpose. etc/all.scss is the place where you dump all CSS that has nowhere else to go, so to speak.

Comment: I understand that. I am trying to use my theme's sass variables in conjunction with the etc/all.scss file.

Comment: The only option I'm sure will work is to move all SASS code that depends on custom variables to some component's SASS. Another option would be to hack the build-impl.xml to process `all.scss` differently, but that's kind of extreme in my book. Easier to move SASS code around.